Apache Procrun with jdk21.0.5_11 -java.awt.HeadlessException: The application does not have desktop access
Some of the JAVA AWT Components are not getting rendered when we use amazon corretto version jdk21.0.5_11 and Apache Procrun
we are using Apache Procrun to run our java application as a service. But Apache Procrun is not working with jdk21.0.5_11
It is giving the following exception
Unknown error = java.awt.HeadlessException:
The application does not have desktop access,
but this program performed an operation which requires it.
It works great with previous version of JDK jdk21.0.1_12. The same program works great if you execute it from eclipse or from a command prompt or using a jar file. It only fails if we execute it from Procrun service
